# Add disable attribute to Button component in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I can't figure out how to disable a button for a custom Button component in React. I want it to be conditional so it only disables when the word is written.

```
<Button disabled>Disabled</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of the Button component : https://codesandbox.io/s/y08xk0vzxz

And here is the code :

```
function Button({ disabled, children }) {
  return <button disabled={disabled}>{children}</button>;
}
```

You can check the log in codesanbox and see that by default if noting is specify for the value in your JSX, the value of the prop is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
let isEmpty = true;

<Button disabled={isEmpty}>Disabled</Button>
```

here default value of disabled is `true`. We also can pass conditional value as needed